# Remap Fn+F3 from XF86Sleep to XF86MonBrightnessUp

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, brightness, mint

I have got a new laptop which is Toshiba Sattelite Pro R50 and I've installed Linux Mint 17.1 on it. After a while it turned out brightness buttons are mapped incorrectly.

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> is mapped to XF86Sleep

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> is mapped to XF86Battery

The keys should be mapped to XF86MonBrightnessUp and XF86MonBrightnessDown respectively.

I've not found any working solution for this issue.

There's one using `xbingkeys` that allows me to bind XF86Battery to a script, but it still doesn't work for XF86Sleep.

`.xbindkeysrc` file below. The `/usr/bin/caja` it's just for testing purposes.

```
# brightness down
"/usr/bin/caja"
    m:0x0 + c:244
    XF86Battery

# brightness up
"/usr/bin/caja"
    m:0x0 + c:150
    XF86Sleep
```

I'm looking for a solution to rebind keys to brightness down/up keys or at least run custom script when the combination is pressed. Currently <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> puts the computer into sleep mode which is very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [xmodmap](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/xmodmap.1.html).

If you want to have the changes you did with it persist, create a script in `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d` and just add all the xmodmap commands you executed before, each on its own line, into it.  The existing scripts there seem to be bash scripts, so start with the line

```
#!/bin/bash
```

You will need root permissions to create that file, read about that in your favorite linux wiki if you aren't familiar with it. If you created the script, you'll still have to make it executable with `chmod +x /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME.sh` – for more details, again, go to your favorite linux wiki.